# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 No appropriate prime between 1024 and 1024 is available. en

Tags: jsch

I am looking to connect to a server where they support the following key exchange method
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
ecdh-sha2-nistp384 
ecdh-sha2-nistp256 
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
diffie-hellman-group14
diffie-hellman-group

I am using jsch jsch-0.1.53 and using RSA private/public key to connect to the server. This works fine before not until the server was changed and now returning this strange error

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 No appropriate prime between 1024 and 1024 is available.  en
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:899)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:294)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:154)

I am running and compiling the project using java 1.6.0_16.

Any idea how to resolve this issue please ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with jsch 0.1.53 and Java 1.7.0_05
It got solved when I update to Java 1.8_101

Comment: I've updated to Java 1.8.0_111 and still doesn't work. Is there any configuration that needs to set?

Comment: @JeffreyHitosis another approach will be to use a library different for the problematic operation. For example, in a project where I was forced to use Java 1.7 and couldn't fix the problem upgrading, I overwrite JCE configuration in runtime with BouncyCastle cryptography library that performs the operation with no errors.

Comment: The weird thing here is when I updated my java version, and run the application through eclipse, I can connect to server. However,  the issue suddenly appeared again.